# Create table 1 in R

Tags: r, datatable, hmisc

Does anyone know how to create a typical table 1 in clinical papers using R?  To be more specific, I need to report mean/SD for continuous variables and count/percentages for categorical variables for the whole population and also for each group defined by a categorical variable.  I would also like to report the p-value for the differences between groups.  I saw people has done this for continuous variables only but not for categorical variables.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: look at `knitr`, `xtable`, `sweave`, `latex`, and lots of other things found in the [reproducible research task view on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ReproducibleResearch.html)

Comment: there's also lots of good stuff in Frank Harrell's book (*Regression Modeling Strategies*), `Hmisc` package (e.g. the `?describe` function), and `rms` package.  As usual, if you gave us a reproducible example of what you want it would help (e.g. "I want to replicate such-and-such a table [paste snapshot of table from the paper], but using these data [provide the data] instead") -- as always, see http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000

Comment: Super late, but what I'm developing to make my medical research easy may be what you want.

https://github.com/kaz-yos/tableone

Comment: `install.packages("finalfit")` is great for this. 
http://finalfit.org/articles/finalfit.html

Answer (score 2):

First part, partially answered by:

```
require(Hmisc)
latex(describe(DFnew[1:400, c("Sex", "GGT")], descript='Table1: Descriptive Statistics')
```

You will find a lot more worked examples at [Harrell's various webpages dedicated to reproducible research.](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/StatReport) In particular you should look at page 30 (Table 9) in Harrell's [monograph describing the tools he has constructed.](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/StatReport/summary.doc.pdf) It's essentially all you were asking for.

[image]